# Check if table contains number

Tags: lua

I need to check if a table contains a specific number that is known.

e.g. My variable is `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` and I want to know how I can check if that variable contains the number `3`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A variable can't "contain" multiple numbers. Provide more information: What is the type of your variable? Is it a string `"12345"`? Or is it a number `12345` and you want to determine whether a certain digit occurs in it's base 10 representation? Or is it perhaps even a list of numbers (a table) `{1,2,3,4,5}`? The answer to your question depends on the type of your variable.

Comment: Sorry for not stating my question correctly, its a table of numbers

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over the values of your table and compare them against the number:

```lua
function contains(table, number)
    for key, value in pairs(table) do if value == number then return true end end
    return false
end
```

this will search through the values of both hash & list part. Usage based on your example: `var = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; assert(contains(var, 3))`.

Answer (score 0):

If your list is sorted, you can use a binary search:

```lua
function contains(t, num)
    local upper = #t
    local lower = 1
    while upper >= lower do
        local mid = math.floor((lower + upper) / 2)
        local v = t[mid]
        if v < num then
            lower = mid + 1
        elseif v > num then
            upper = mid - 1
        else -- v == num
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end
```